# flutter unable to load image assets

Tags: flutter, dart

this how I called image in my app

```
Image.asset('assets/user.jpg')
```

this is my pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
   -assets/user.jpg
```

and I get this error

```
Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assets/user.jpg)
```

Comment: It would be easy to debug this if you could attach a pic of the image's directory.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider indentation for assets in `pubspec.yaml`

```
assets:
  - assets/user.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your indentation is not correct. It should be like this:

```
assets:
  - assets/user.jpg
```

2. Make sure `user.jpg` is placed in `assets` folder in your project's
   main directory (not inside `lib` folder)
3. After doing this, make sure you rebuild your app to see these changes.